How to perform a sum on POSIXT values using Dplyr?
I have the following dataset
df <- data.frame(
 courts = c("Court 1", "Court 1", "Court 2"),
 time = c("1:00 hrs", "3:00 hrs", "2:00 hrs") 
)

I now remove the space like this
df <- df %>%
 mutate(
 time_without_hrs = sub(" hrs", "", time)
)

And format the hrs as date.time
 df$time_without_hrs <- as.POSIXct(df$time_without_hrs, format="%H:%M")

However, now when I want to sum the courts by hours ....
summary_df <- df %>%
 group_by(courts) %>%
 summarize(
 sum_value1 = sum(time_without_hrs),
 )

I get the following error. Any thoughts on what goes wrong?
Error in `summarize()`:
ℹ In argument: `sum_value1 = sum(time_without_hrs)`.
ℹ In group 1: `courts = "Court 1"`.
Caused by error in `Summary.POSIXct()`:
! 'sum' not defined for "POSIXt" objects
Run `rlang::last_trace()` to see where the error occurred.


POSIXct isn't really the appropriate class to be converting these to. It represents the seconds since 1970 so a sum of them doesn't make sense (see ?POSIXct) You might want to try setting units to hours or minutes and summing. Are they always full hours or do you need to calculate the total minutes in after the ':'?

The error message is clear: "! 'sum' not defined for "POSIXt" objects".
Try lubridate's hm and hour functions to convert the original character representation into a numeric value representing the number of whole hours.
library(lubridate)

df %>%
  mutate(time_in_hrs=hour(
    hm(time)
  )) %>%
  group_by(courts) %>%
  summarize(
    sum_value1 = sum(time_in_hrs),
  )


# A tibble: 2 x 2
  courts  sum_value1
  <chr>        <dbl>
1 Court 1          4
2 Court 2          2


lubridate saves a lot codes, +1! You can summarize with .by = to make your coder even more concise.

Convert the time to "difftime" class and then sum.  Finally convert that to numeric.
Optionally omit %>% as.numeric if a difftime object is ok as the output for the time column.
Have incorporated suggestion from comments by @ThomasIsCoding
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  summarize(time = time %>%
       as.difftime(format = "%H:%M hrs") %>%
       sum %>% 
       as.numeric, .by = courts)
##    courts time
## 1 Court 1    4
## 2 Court 2    2

Note
Input used
df <- data.frame(
 courts = c("Court 1", "Court 1", "Court 2"),
 time = c("1:00 hrs", "3:00 hrs", "2:00 hrs") 
)


Excellent use of difftime, +1! Actually you can use format = "%H:%M hrs" in as.difftime to save sub(...).

Thanks. Good idea. Have incorporated.

In your case, what you want to sum up is the time interval (difference), not the time instance that POSIXct represents.
You can use as.difftime like below
df %>%
    summarise(sum_hrs = sum(as.difftime(time,
        format = "%H:%M hrs",
        units = "hours"
    )), .by = courts)

gives
   courts sum_hrs
1 Court 1 4 hours
2 Court 2 2 hours


Best answer, should be the accepted one.
